# concat() function XPath Evaluation fails while using with AutoPilot in VTD-XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath, concatenation, vtd-xml

Using the VTD-XML 2.11 (Java) API, when evaluating the XPath expression **concat()** on the Simple text or xml elments, instead getting a result of 2.0, it fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ximpleware.XPathEvalException:  Function Expr can't eval to node set 
    at com.ximpleware.FuncExpr.evalNodeSet(FuncExpr.java:1033)
    at com.ximpleware.AutoPilot.evalXPath(AutoPilot.java:876)
```

Here is the following program:

```
private static String getElementValue() throws XPathParseException, XPathEvalException, NavException {
    String value = null;

    VTDGen gen = new VTDGen();
    gen.setDoc(data.getBytes());
    gen.parse(false);

    VTDNav nav = gen.getNav();

    AutoPilot pilot = new AutoPilot(nav);
    pilot.selectXPath("concat(\"Hello\", \"Mr Buddy\")");

    int bufferIndex = NO_MATCH;
    if((bufferIndex = pilot.evalXPath()) != NO_MATCH) {
        value= nav.getXPathStringVal();
    }
    System.out.println(value);
} // end of getElementValue()
```

Comment: I think u might want to try evalXpathToString method...

Comment: Then how i can pass the xpath

Comment: If you have any example how to concatenate two xpaths or one xpath + constant value.

Comment: SelectXpath is the same, the difference is how you eval the xpath.. Instead of using evalxpath, which assumes returning a nodeset , use evalxpath2string..

Comment: pilot.evalXPathToString(); doesn't take any arguments i mean Xpath value.

Comment: Ap.Selectxpath(); then... Ap.evalxpath2string() returns the string value that you look 4

Comment: AutoPilot pilot = new AutoPilot(nav);
pilot.selectXPath(xpath);
String value = pilot.evalXPathToString();                        here selectXPath() it self it is throwing exception

Comment: It appears evalxpath causes exception in your question.. doesn't it

Comment: selectXPath(xpath) it self it is failing and it is giving following error. Exception in thread "main" com.ximpleware.XPathEvalException:  Function Expr can't eval to node set

Comment: selectXPath does not throw those exceptions. It is evalXPath that throws those 2 exceptions. Please look more closely or unless you have new log that differs from above.

Comment: You are concatenating strings, not a valid xpath node set.

Comment: if i give proper xpaths also not working.  This is my xpath. String xpath = "concat(/users/user/firstname, /users/user/lastname)";

Comment: String data = "<users>"+
             "<user>"+
              "<firstname>1</firstname>"+  
              "<lastname>2</lastname>"+
               "</user>"+
          "</users>";

Comment: the above one is data

Comment: The code to get the value is String ev = null;
  
  AutoPilot pilot = new AutoPilot(nav);
  pilot.selectXPath(xpath);
  
  int bufferIndex = NO_MATCH;
  if((bufferIndex = pilot.evalXPath()) != NO_MATCH) {
   ev = nav.getXPathStringVal();
  }
  
  return ev;

Comment: concat() function itself it is not working properly.

Comment: before I focus on the new issue that you raised, can you verify that "pilot.selectXPath("concat(\"Hello\", \"Mr Buddy\")" and "evalXPath2String()" works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code and it seems to work fine for me... look at it and let me know your thoughts..

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
public class concatTest{
    public static void main(String s1[]) throws Exception {
        VTDGen vg= new VTDGen();
        String s = "<users><user><firstName>some </firstName><lastName> one</lastName></user></users>";
        vg.setDoc(s.getBytes());
        vg.parse(false);
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
        ap.selectXPath("concat('good', ' luck')");
        System.out.println(" concat output ==>"+ap.evalXPathToString());
        ap.selectXPath("concat(/, '')");
        ap.bind(vn);
        System.out.println(" concat output ==>"+ap.evalXPathToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi i want one more thing if xpath value is not matching i don't want to concat. How we will achieve.

Comment: Can you be specific? what do you mean by not matching? any example?

Comment: For example concat('Hello', /users/firstNames) here firstNames xpath is not matched the result is Hello. What i am asking is if the xpath is not matched i don't want do concat() so result will be null or empty.

Comment: This xpath is ask certainly to be done... if there is any condition attached to it, in xpath 1.0, this can't be done with in the expression, but you can do it programmatically, i.e. outside the expression using code logic to make this happen.. if you open another question, I can probably submit a full answer ...